# How to get server message correctly

Tags: android, sockets, inputstream

**Problem**

I send the message "12345" from the socket server to the client:

```
myPrintWriter.println("12345");
```

After that I read this message on client:

```
int c;
while ((c = inputStream.read( )) != -1)
{
    byte[] buffer2 = new byte[1];
    buffer2[0] = (byte) c;
    String symbol = new String(buffer2 , "UTF-8");
    String symbolCode = Integer.toString((int)buffer2[0]);
    Log.v(symbol, symbolCode);
}
Log.v("c == -1", "Disconnected");
```

What I see in log:
[image]

With

```
out.println("abcrefg");
```

[image]

**Why?** I think it's line termination symbol. I need to get string "12345" or any other and next strings correctly. Help me please.

---

If I use bufferedReader.readLine():

```
try 
{
    byte[] b1 = new byte[1];
    int dataInt = clientSocket.getInputStream().read();
    b1[0] = (byte)dataInt;

    final String data;
    if(dataInt == -1)
        connectionIsLost();

    if(dataInt != -1)
    {
        String c = new String(b1, "UTF-8");
        data = c + inToServer.readLine();
    }
    else
        data = inToServer.readLine();

    if (data != null)
    {
        Log.v("data", data);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
        {
            //data parsing
        });
    }
} 
catch (IOException e){...}
```

If I send messages slow:

```
> V/data(5301): -3#Leo#alone in the dark 11-12
> V/message(5301): Leo: alone in the dark 11-12
> V/data(5301): -3#Leo#cgh 11-12 
> V/message(5301): Leo: cgh 11-12 
> V/data(5301): -3#Leo#c
> V/message(5301): Leo: c 11-12 
> V/data(5301): -3#Leo#x 11-12 
> V/message(5301): Leo: x
> V/data(5301): -3#Leo#d 11-12
> V/message(5301): Leo: d
```

But if I do it faster:

```
> V/data(5512): -3#Leo#fccc
> V/message(5512): Leo: fccc
> V/data(5512): -3#Leo#ccc
> V/data(5512): -3#Leo#cccc
> V/message(5512): Leo: ccc
> V/message(5512): Leo: cccc
> V/data(5512): --3#Leo#cccc //<-----error
> V/data(5512): 3-3#Leo#cccc //<-----error
> V/data(5512): #Leo#xdd
```

Exception :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have in mind the `UTF-8` enconding may result in more than one byte per character, and your code above will fail to correctly handle them.

If you want to read `String` encoded in `UTF-8`, is better to have them decoded by a ´BufferdReader` and getting it line by line.

Example code:

```
    String line;
    BufferedReader _in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(_socket.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"));

    try {
         while ((line = _in.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, line);
         }
         Log.d(TAG, "Connection is closed");
    } catch (Exception e) {
         Log.d(TAG, "Connection is closed");
    }
```

Regards.

Comment: So I cant see my connection state when inputStream returns -1.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your comment, but with the code above you get `null` when no more strings in buffer. If you want to check connection status, you can still look at the `InputStream` or the `Socket`.

Comment: Yes I cant, but so I create some problems: InputStream.read() removes first byte out my InputStream. I tried to connect this byte with other line and all is fine, but if messages come too quickly, for some reason the first byte doesn't splice with other line. After that I receive an exception.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand your comment. I need to be clear on what you want to achive and on what exactly is your problem.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how to test for the connection closure.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely it is CR/LF.
It is there because you are using `println`. Try `print` instead.